# Changing the background color in html5

Tags: css, html

I have no background on HTML5. and im trying to change some things on this template that im using http://html5up.net/escape-velocity/

I wanna change the red color on the introduction. or maybe change the bg to an image. I cant seem to find the color code on the css.

Comment: Search this class selector `.wrapper-style1 .title`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized

Comment: question seems fine to me

Comment: Your browser has tools to open up pages and let you inspect the DOM. F12 for example in Chrome.

Comment: Well, you have to start somewhere with web development, just probably not with this question!

Comment: "I have no background on HTML5" --> You should get some, then. SO is for specific questions, it is not a free crowdsourcing site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.wrapper-style1 {
    background: #e97770;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's here:

```
.wrapper-style1 {
    background: #e97770
```